# Problems with <img/> tag in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, image

So, I'm making a website in wordpress for the first time, and I'm using an FTP connection to the server and so on. I'm editing in the theme I'm using, and making a homepage. But I've ran into the problem, that whenever I type
 `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/C8Ws3dO.jpg"/>`
It works just fine, but when I try adding the directory or whatever, it gets mad and shows a little image icon instead 
`<img src="hp-image.jpg"/>`

Comment: Oh, just to make sure noone says "You sure you got the right directory?". Yes. http://puu.sh/upBLa/18626797af.png

Comment: Files in your theme's folder are not in the root of the site. So yeah, it is a path problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the FULL directory path name.

```
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/hp-image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Taaaanks <3 Also dont judge me im an idiot i know XD

Comment: No problem! It's alright I been through the same situation lol